# Debugging php code with xdebug using Netbeans

Tags: php, xdebug, netbeans-7

I am very new to php and am trying to built a full debugging environment for php.
I have downloaded Netbeans and have already **wamp** installed.

I found on net that **xdebug** is a good utility for debugging.
I have downloaded it. 
What exact changes are required in configuration files.

I am using **windows 7**. and also want to ask " is the **Zend framework** required to be downloaded ?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the information you need is here: http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug

Answer (score 1):

The [following wizard](http://xdebug.org/wizard.php) is a step-by step installation instruction for xdebug, it'll tell you basically three things:

1. A download link for php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.3-vc9.dll
2. Where to copy (which folder): php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.3-vc9.dll (probably: 
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext`).
3. How to edit php.ini - what line/s to add/comment (for me it was to add: 
   `zend_extension = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.3-vc9.dll"` and remove all the other `zend` lines).

Comment: It's bulit-in PHP installation for windows.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend the Netbeans wiki. Or try this simple tutorial http://martinsikora.com/debugging-php-in-netbeans-using-xdebug

If you tried already, try to be more specific on what is not working for you (include error messages etc.)

The Zend framework is not needed.